# Issue increasing memsize to desired value in SAS

Tags: memory, sas

I am running a proc mixed code where the default 2GB provides insufficient memory to run.

I changed the memsize in the config file to 4G and it did change to 4GB when checking in `proc options; run;`. However, it is still not enough for proc mixed to execute.

When I change it to 8G, I ran `proc options; run;` to check the memsize and it was still stuck at 4GB unfortunately.

I have a 16GB computer so I thought I would not come across such an issue. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running 64-bit SAS? The only reason I can think of it would be limited is if you're using a 32-bit version of SAS, or if you changed the wrong config file. The standard config file location should be:

`C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\sasv9.cfg`

If you're running UTF-8, it is located in:

`C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\u8\sasv9.cfg`

Changing -MEMSIZE to 8G should change it.

One test would be to invoke SAS with this option set explicitly:

`sas.exe -MEMSIZE 8G`

```
proc options group=memory;
run;
```

Should show:

`MEMSIZE=8589934592`

If it does not show 8GB, you must be running a 32-bit version of SAS. SAS will automatically set the max memory to 4GB even if the config file is above that value.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am running 32-bit version. Guess I will have to change to 64-bit. Thanks for the tip!